# Why I can't add values into a table?

Tags: php, yii

Good afternoon. Here's a question, I want to fill in data for SiteController inside table Verification. Table code:

```
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `type` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    `username` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `code` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `created` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `expired` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL
```

After filling, the if($verifycationModel->save()){ return false and the exit occurs. Here is the code:

```
             if($model->save()){
                // Verification
                $verifycationModel = new Verification;
                //Type of verification
                $verifycationModel->type = 1;
                //Username
                $verifycationModel->username = $model->username;
                //Random Code
                $verifycationModel->code = time() . mt_rand (11111, 99999);
                //Created Date
                $verifycationModel->created = time();
                //Expired date CurrentDate + 86400 (24 hours)
                $verifycationModel->expired = time() + 86400;
                //Not authorizing for default
                $verifycationModel->active = 0;
                if($verifycationModel->save()){
                    // Saving "verify_id" to
                    $userModel = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$verifycationModel->username));
                    $userModel->verify_id = $userModel->id;
                    $userModel->save();
                }
                else
                {
                   exit();
                }
```

What do I need to do to make this code work and return true, but not exit?

My solution: 
In this situation, the decision was to analyze all incoming debugger values ​​and variables. The results showed that there are fields in which rules()
prescribed as mandatory, but they are not sent ... Such as checkbox, etc. Added default values ​​and it worked.

Comment: You can get model errors by calling `$verifycationModel->getErrors()` method. Also can you show your `rules()` method in `Verification` class?

Comment: Yes, problem was in rules(). Thank you!

Comment: If you have found the solution go ahead and add it below to close the question.

Comment: If no validation is needed, you can also provide false to the method `$verifycationModel->save(false)`